# How to list unique Subject Alternative Names from a Java TrustStore (JKS) file

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate, jks, truststore

Is there any simple way (preferably from Command Line Interface) to list the unique Subject Alternative Names for all the certificates inside a Java TrustStore (JKS) file?

Comment: `keytool -list -v [-keystore $file -storepass $pw]` shows all (known) extensions including SAN, thus including a lot of other stuff you need to ignore or filter out with something like `awk '/^SubjectAlternativeName/,/^]/' | sort -u` -- but that isn't programming or development, thus offtopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Java developer a small Java program can do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName= "website_certs.jks";
    char[] password = "".toCharArray();
    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(fileName), password);
        Set<Object> subjAltNames = Collections.list(ks.aliases()).stream().flatMap(alias -> {
            try {
                return ((X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias)).getSubjectAlternativeNames().stream();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return Stream.empty();
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        subjAltNames.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The only thing that is strange in your question is that a trust store usually contains root or intermediate CA certificates. But only leaf certificates installed on a web server have a subject alternative name. Therefore this code only works for trust stores that contains leaf/server certificates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, marked as accepted :)